# why I can't download pics from facebook at full size using python

Tags: python, facebook, python-requests

For my CS exam I have written a python code to download images from a user account using Graph APIs but I have faced a problem I am not able to fix:

When I open the pic in the browser to download it it is located at the following URL:

```
https://scontent.fbzo1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/276154675_133885455881794_6427257905137797718_n.jpg?_nc_cat=108&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=9267fe&_nc_ohc=YLBzlwDAyFMAX-xSuA2&_nc_ht=scontent.fbzo1-2.fna&oh=00_AT8Id6JhclEoVKJSWjxj2QPFxJJV4AiyuLQRfaEP02-81A&oe=625D705A
```

but when I open it from a python application it tries to download the pic from a different URL:

```
https://scontent.fbzo1-2.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/276154675_133885455881794_6427257905137797718_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s720x720&_nc_cat=108&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=2d5d41&_nc_ohc=YLBzlwDAyFMAX-xSuA2&_nc_ht=scontent.fbzo1-2.fna&edm=AJfPMC4EAAAA&oh=00_AT8deCIWQLP87HEgyDOa1GIAcGBb9L7bElubSoHzidxvvQ&oe=625D705A
```

and it has a different resolution from the original!

I will post here some code, if you need the full code, I can add it.
this is the downloading function:

```
# retrieve the post id to download the image from fb posst

# download and save image from permalink url
def download_and_save_img(img_url, img_name):

    # retrieve only the img name / the file extention seams to generate an error -> setting it manualy
    last_slash  = img_name.rfind('/')
    file_ext    = img_name.rfind('.')
    img_name    = img_name[last_slash+1:file_ext]

    # download the image with a GET request and write it to an img file
    # print(img_url)
    img_response    = requests.get(img_url)
    image           = open("fl-tw-fb/" + img_name + '.jpg', "wb")
    image.write(img_response.content)
    image.close()
```

And here is the call

```
response = get_img_link_from_fb_postID(post_id['post_id'])
response_json = json.loads(response)
print(response_json)
img_url = response_json['attachments']['data'][0]['media']['image']['src']

# finaly download the img from fb and save it
download_and_save_img(img_url, line)
```

when printing the `response_json` I get:

```
{
   "attachments":{
      "data":[
         {
            "media":{
               "image":{
                  "height":405,
                  "src":"https://scontent.fbzo1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/278102009_133887052548301_9150026685369816171_n.jpg?stp=dst-jpg_s720x720&_nc_cat=100&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=2d5d41&_nc_ohc=WF5mnEaaoKcAX9GxsvH&_nc_ht=scontent.fbzo1-1.fna&edm=AJfPMC4EAAAA&oh=00_AT9T6TUvuRni6TEcLz7oteYsH8E_6yko2FRSEXTH9MPppQ&oe=625BDBB7",
                  "width":720
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "id":"102956292308044_133887055881634"
}
```

Any idea?

Edit: adding code for @WizKid:

```
# retrieve the image link present in a given post_id
def get_img_link_from_fb_postID(post_id):

    # (extended) access token
    at  = 'xxx'  # removed 

    # build the url
    url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/' + post_id + '?fields=attachments%7Bmedia%7D&access_token=' + at
    try:
        response = requests.get(url)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error in get img link from post_id: {e}")
    return response.content
```

Comment: I believe the resolution is controlled by the `stp=dst-jpg_s720x720` query parameter, which you could try to remove after`urllib.parse` and rebuilding the address

Comment: What does get_img_link_from_fb_postID do?

Comment: @OneCricketeer: I tried manually to change the request URL removing the resolution 720x720 but it turns out into a wrong URL error. The  JSON I posted is the server response so I don't think I can change it and get something from it.

Comment: @WizKid I have added the code to the post. Take a look. It just takes a post ID and retrieve the img link from the post.

Comment: Removed how? You can't just replace 720x720, you'll need to remove the whole stp query parameter (which didn't exist in the first address, so removing it should be fine). For example, replace `stp=dst-jpg_s720x720&` with an empty string

Comment: Changing the URL doesn't work. The URL is signed. You have to ask the API for the size you want.

Comment: @OneCricketeer exctly what I did but got an error

Comment: @WizKid how do I do that? I find some old posts dated 2015 but not applicable now. And how do I do that if I don't know a priori the image size? Maybe with type parameter!?

Comment: Update: even this: `https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/102956292308044_133887055881634?fields=full_picture` gives the same problem: 720px sized picture